# (Privileged) Access Management solution that integrates into the workflow of developers

Tags: authentication

Tl;dr:
We need an access management solution for 200 admins and developers to access internal servers. It should be possible to not only use a webshell, but also use it as a proxy for local programs like DB GUI tools or scripts. It shouldn't be too complicated to setup. We already looked at Teleport and Cyberark. We likes the approach of Teleport, but it had problems on a security level and Cyberark seems like a too complicated (and expensive) approach.

**Context:**
I am working as an information security officer in a medium to large company that also handles PII and we want to secure the access to our internal servers as our network structure is very open at the moment especially for our developers as they have to access a lot of servers regularely.
Our main incident we are looking at is the case of a compromised client which an attacker might use for lateral movement in our network.
The solution shall be used by our developers and administrators.
We aim to include ~200 Users and the setup shouldn'd be too complicated as the team that would implement it is a bit short staffed at the time.
We are still in doubt if we want to run it on-premise or use a cloud service as a hijacked saas provider will give any attacker administrative access to our internal servers.

**Caveats:**
In the past year we have looked into PAM solutions as in our opinion SSH, SQL, ... type accesses from developers can be counted as "privileged" (in some way) even though they aren't technically administrators/root an the target machines.
This also makes it hard for us to find a fitting solution because of the specific requirements of our developers and we have a hard time to get the devs on board with our plans as they are afraid that "they are unable to work" with such a solution or have too many hoops to jump through for daily tasks.

Some solutions provide a webshell which is already sufficient for many administrators, but the devs need the ability to use "native" ssh connection to run scripts or connect DB GUI Tools like DBeaver or MySQLWorkbench with the target system to work efficently.

Two of our main caveats are that accessing a server (or at least ones containing productiond data) should requite a 2FA login (preferrably compliant with FIDO2 to be used with a yubikey or Apple-TouchID) and the second is that it should not be possible for an attacker on a compromised client to piggy-back on an exisiting connection and open further connections if the user has established one via MFA.

**Evaluated solutions:**
*Teleport:*
I personally really likes the approach of Teleport as its workflow seemed to intergrate into the daily work of our developers really nicely.
But we had some problems with Teleport:

Their support was really slow to answer our questions and the pricing model is intransparent.

The installation is agent-based and we prefer an agent-less apporach

The way connections are established didn't seem to be secure enough for us and the support also confirmed that it might be possible to hijack an existing connection.

*Cyberark:*
We already had contact with the Cyberark team and they seem very eager to sell us their product.
But on one hand their solution is out of budget atm and even if they comply to our budget, they presented a deployment plan which includes 230! hours of planning, setup and maintainance time just to get it running as well as requiring multiple hardware machines (no virtualization). And this doesn't really fit with our expectations of it being "not too complicated".
Also, looking at our developers, the usability seems a bit lackluster for our use cases.

Does someone have any experience/suggestions for a solution that might fit our use-cases?
A lot of information on the internet is just advertisement...
Is a PAM solution even the correct approach for this?
And what is your opinion of cloud-based PAM Services?